# How to send notifications in MEAN stack app using Socket.io from different modules?

Tags: socket.io, mean-stack

I have an app written using MEAN stack. I have different modules in the app, as 'Users', 'Messages', 'Sections' etc...

the client should not sent any notification to the server, only the server send messages to the clients in the rooms.

How can I configure the socket.io to be used in the different modules:

- so when the user do login in the Users module, to add it to a room
- when a user post a message, and after the messages inserted to the mongodb to emit the message (from the Messages module)
- when a user update a section, and after the section is updated in the mongodb, to emit the change to the users in the room.

Something as below:

users.js

```
exports.Users = function(io) {

  ...
  UsersCollection.save(...) {
    ...
    io.join('some room');
    ...
  }
}
```

messages.js

```
exports.Messages = function(io) {

  ...
  MessagesCollection.save(...) {
    ...
    io.to('some room').emit('new_message', msg):
    ...
  }
}
```

sections.js

```
exports.Sections = function(io) {

  ...
  SectionsCollection.update(...) {
    ...
    io.to('some room').emit('section_updated', msg):
    ...
  }
}
```

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var users = require('users')(io);
var messages = require('messages')(io);
var sections = require('sections')(io);
...

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('someone connected')
});
```

What is the best way to make such a thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by using EventEmitter in the following way:

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
**var events = require('events');
var serverEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
var users = require('users')(serverEmitter);
var messages = require('messages')(serverEmitter);
var sections = require('sections')(serverEmitter);**
...

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  serverEmitter.on('new_message', function (data) {
        socket.to('some room').emit('new_message', msg):
    });
});
```

And later in the apis I used the emitter as:

```
serverEmitter.emit('new_message', msg);
```

Thanks.